# Detect RPC connection loss from server-side on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, rpc

Is there any way to check the status of the RPC connection from the server-side? I am looking for a way to detect if the connection from the client is lost, be it client crash or other connectivity issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Context Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373969(VS.85).aspx) for managing server state between calls for a particular client. RPC uses keep-alive's to detect client disconnects and will execute your context handle rundown routine if the client disconnects.

Comment: Does this mean that, if I want to have the server detect client departure on an existing RPC API, the best approach would be to add a function that returns a context handle that does nothing but identify the client, and when its rundown function executes I know that client is gone? That sounds like it would require the minimal amount of change, though I was really hoping I could do it without any client-side changes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Mo Flanagan's answer is the best IMHO.  Some more context.

If you're using binding handles, there is no way of tracking state across RPC calls and the concept of a "client disconnect" is essentially meaningless - you still need to return from the RPC call.

If you're using context handles, then the RPC runtime library will call the _rundown function when the client disconnects.

When that routine is called, the server can clean up whatever it needs to.

Comment: I just had to answer this one for old times sake. I used to work on the RPC team at MSFT, this brought back memories of RPCDBG ;)